# double integral initial condition

Tags: integration

For an initial condition problem, if I take the first integral:

$\int1 dt = t + C1$

But if I take the 2nd integral, do I end up with:

$\int (t + C1)dt = \frac{1}{2} t^2 + C1t + C2$

or does the constant somehow get combined to a single constant in the end:

$\int(\int(1)dt)dt = \frac{1}{2}t^2 + C3$

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. +1 because you have formatted the question properly (unusual for newcomers)!

Comment: Generally, $n$th order will have $n$ free constants. So if you integrate twice you expect two. Looking specifically at this, how would you combine $C_1t+C_2$ into $C_3$? You would have lost the $t$. Also try using the underline symbol before the 2 in $C2$ to get $C_2$. It looks neater!

Comment: Is that enough? Or do you need more?

Comment: You said I will have n free constants. What does "free" mean? Free of the variable t, or free to be any value? I don't think you can combine $C_1 t + C_2$ into $C_3$, so the answer should be $\frac{1}{2} t^2 + C_1 t + C_2$ ?? Do I need multiple initial conditions to find the values of both C numbers?

Comment: Free to be any value. You are correct that you cannot combine $C_1$ and $C_2$! Well done on the subscripts. :)

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed your last question. In general you need $n$ conditions to determine $n$ constants. Here you would expect two.

Answer (score 2):

we obtain
$\int dt=t+C_1$
and
$\int t+C_1dt=\frac{t^2}{2}+C_1t+C_2$
you can not $C_1t+C_2$ simplify to $C_3$ since $C_1t$ isn't constant.
Sonnhard.